# Grails compilation error: unable to resolve class JSON

Tags: java, eclipse, json, grails

I have the following setup, grails 2.0.3, STS, and I'm doing this in one of my controllers:

```
render(['car': contactL] as JSON)
```

When I run the application I get the following error:

I have read about the error, but none of the solutions have worked for me, I have tried cleaning, upgrading, using the Grails Tools -> Refresh dependencies but it gave me:

```
grails> | Error Error running script null: Cannot invoke method trim() on null object (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

I'm also getting this error in my project:

```
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for groovy.lang.GroovyObject. Fix the build path then try building this project    Ristretto       Unknown Java Problem
```

What's you diagnose?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally managed to get it working, I switched workspace, and added my project - problem solved.

Answer (score 13):

To fix the "unable to resolve class JSON" error, you should just have to import it:

```
import grails.converters.JSON
...
class MyController {
    ...
    render [car: contactL] as JSON
```

Comment: I have tried that one, Groovy:unable to resolve class grails.converters.JSON

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I haven't used STS a whole lot, but sounds like something's wrong there (a conclusion that you've already come to yourself). Sorry I can't help much more; I'll probably delete this answer - you might want to add the fact that you've imported that into your question, though.

Comment: All answers are appreciated :) It worked until yesterday, what I did was delete my maven and ivy-cache, one point it was telling me that a pom.xml-file was not present...I still haven't solved the issue

Comment: In the end, I used a new workspace and added the repository - that solved it.

Comment: @marko - Good to know. You can probably add that as an answer and accept it to help future visitors.